# In which circumstances Java reference equality could be different to equals() equality for an object of a type which has not overridden equals()?

Tags: java

Is there any magic hanging around anywhere that could mean that

```
(object0 == object1) != (object0.equals(object1))
```

where object0 and object1 are both of a certain type which hasn't overridden Object.equals()?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. That's exactly the definition of Object.[equals()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

*...this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true) ...*

```
public boolean equals( Object o ) { 
   return this == o;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if by "The type of `object0` doesn't override `Object.equals()`" you mean the specific type and not a superclass.

If `object0` and `object1` are of type B, B extends A, and A overrides `equals(Object obj)` but B doesn't, then it is possible that B doesn't override `equals(Object obj)` but `(object0 == object1) != (object0.equals(object1))`.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if `object0 == null` and `object1 == null`, the first will deliver `true`, and the second a `NullPointerException`. Apart from that, there should be no observable difference.

Answer (score 3):

Although the objects don't override `equals()` themselves, it is possible that one of superclasses of the object overrides the `equals()` method.

If you are using eclipse: open the `object.java` file and press control-o twice. Type '*equals*' and check if you only see one '*equals*' method: the equals method of Object.

Answer (score 2):

The Object.java src defines its equals method as;

```
 return (this == obj)
```

so no :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `null == null` is true, but `null.equals(null)` is not defined.

Comment: @egaga.  It IS defined ... to throw a NullPointerException!

Answer (score 0):

No, if `equals()` is not overridden, it returns true if the objects are the same identical objects in memory.

Answer (score 0):

No. The actual class of `object0` (not necessarily the declared type of the variable) *must* have overridden `equals()`.  Try printing out:

```
object0.getClass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code for Object.equals:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  151           return (this == obj);
  152       }
  153
```

So, No.