# Java: clone() and equality checks

Tags: java, clone, equality

Perhaps I don't understand how `clone()` works. Shouldn't the return value equal the caller?

```
int[] nums = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
int[] list = nums.clone();
nums.equals(list); //returns false. Why?

for (int ket = 0; ket < list.length; ket++) {

       System.out.println(list[ket] == nums[ket]); //prints out true every time
}

list == nums //false
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the equals implementation of array is the same as Object which is

```
public boolean equals( Object o ) { 
   return this == o;
}
```

<sub>See this also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888815/any-there-any-circumstances-where-java-reference-equality-could-be-different-to-e/888840#888840)</sub>

and in both cases you tested, that's false.  The reference values of the original and the copy are two different objects (with the same value but still different object references).

What the clone method does is create a copy of the given object. When the new object is created, its reference is **different** from the original. That's why `equals` and `==` yield false.

If you want to test for equality two arrays, do as mmyers here: [Arrays.equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574960/java-clone-and-equality-checks/1575007#1575007):

Comment: This is the best answer so far (award it). When you are considering implementing Cloneable, or overrideing equals or hashcode please read: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-1999/jw-01-object.html

My general-purpose advice: don't use Cloneable/clone() but use a copy constructor (which takes only an instance of the current Class as an argument) to make a copy. Save yourself the pain.

Answer (score 7):

Oscar Reyes has the correct answer. I'll just add that [`Arrays.equals()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[])) does exactly the sort of equality comparison that you're looking for.

```
int[] nums = new int[] {0, 1, 2};
int[] list = nums.clone();
System.out.println(Arrays.equals(nums, list)); // prints "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the javadoc for [Objet.clone()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29), it clearly states that while it is typically the case that: "x.clone().equals(x)" will be true, this is not an absolute requirement.

Answer (score 0):

because num.equals doesnt check for the equality of the elements, but it checks whether the two variables point to the same object. In your case, although the elements are the same, but nums and lists point to two different objects.

you could use java.util.Arrays.equals(...) function to do the comparison.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int[],%20int[]%29

Answer (score 0):

nums.equals(list); //false

list == nums; //false

Reason :
By default equals() will behave the same as the “==” operator and compare object locations. here nums and list have different  memory locations.

/* But, equals method is actually meant to compare the contents of 2 objects, and not their location in memory.
So for accomplishing it you can override equals() method. */

list[ket] == nums[ket] //True

The clone is a shallow copy of the array. So, both refers same memory locations. hence it returns true