# Java clone() and equals() check

Tags: java, object, arraylist, clone, equals

For the following class, I understand that `c1.equals(c3)` returns false as `c1.clone()` creates a different reference that points to the same object. But why `carList1.equals(carList2)` returns true? why is it different from `c1.equals(c3)`? Many thanks in advance!

```
class Car implements Cloneable {
   private String plate;   
   private double maxSpeed;     
  public Car(String lp, double max) {
      license = lp;
      maxSpeed = max;
   }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Car c1 = new Car("ABC123", 150.0);
      Car c2 = new Car("ABC123", 150.0);
      Car c3 = (Car) c1.clone();
      ArrayList<Car> carList1 = new ArrayList<Car>();
      carList1.add(c1);
      carList1.add(c2);
      ArrayList carList2 = (ArrayList) carList1.clone();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`clone` of `ArrayList` performs a shallow copy, i.e., it doesn't clone the elements contained within the `ArratList`, it just copies the references. That's why `equals` returns true, since it doesn't compare the references of the ArrayList objects, it compares the elements in the list.

> public Object clone()
>
> Returns a shallow copy of this ArrayList instance. (The elements
>   themselves are not copied.)
>
> public boolean equals(Object o)
>
> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

On the other hand, Car, assuming you don't override its `equals` method to just compare the members, uses the default implementation of Object::equals, which compares object reference, and therefore a cloned Car is not equal to the original.

Comment: Furthermore, if `Car` had a sensible `equals()` implementation instead of relying on the one inherited from `Object`, then `c3.equals(c1)` would be true too.

Comment: but I reckon clone of the object is a shallow copy as well? Plus in this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574960/java-clone-and-equality-checks, the equals() of two array returns false. I am really confused.

Comment: @user3735871 Clone of the object is something you have to implement yourself. And it doesn't matter if it's shallow or not, since you are not overriding the equals method.

Comment: @user3735871 The difference is that `ArrayList` (or rather its ancestor, `AbstractList`) **did** override `equals()` so that only the contents of the list matter.

Comment: @user3735871 In the question you linked to, the compared objects are arrays, not ArrayLists. ArrayList overrides the `equals` method of Object and array does not. That's the reason for the different behavior.

Comment: So you mean the equals() method for ArrayList compares the elements within the ArrayList, while on the other hand, the default equals() method that used to compare Car check the object reference?

Comment: @user3735871 Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!! and thanks for explaining the different equals() between Array and ArrayList!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Car` class hasn't overridden `equals()`. So it evaluates equality simply by object identity, the default behaviour - same as the `==` operator.

On the other hand, ArrayList *has* overridden `equals()` and it does it by calling `equals()` on all the elements in the list. If the lists' elements are all equal, then the lists are equal. And, as another answer mentioned, the `clone()` method creates a new list containing the *same* objects (not copies) as the original.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList doesn't have an `equals()` method. It extends `AbstractList` which defines / implements `equals()`. `clone()` merely copies references, so the objects in both the lists are the same.
From oracle docs : `equals()` does this :

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This
>   implementation first checks if the specified object is this list. If
>   so, it returns true; if not, it checks if the specified object is a
>   list. If not, it returns false; if so, it iterates over both lists,
>   comparing corresponding pairs of elements. If any comparison returns
>   false, this method returns false. If either iterator runs out of
>   elements before the other it returns false (as the lists are of
>   unequal length); otherwise it returns true when the iterations
>   complete.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the implementation of `equals(...)`. The `clone()` function will not copy everything as is as long as you don't override it (which is recommended in the [Clonable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) JavaDoc).

So, you should do two things:

1. Override `clone()`
2. Override `equals()` (and `hashCode()` while you're at it)